# Laravel - Import CSV using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE - failed to import

Tags: laravel

**I tried to import csv file**

here is my code:

```
    private function importFileContents($file_path)
    {
     $query = sprintf("
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE grantee_lists 
            CHARACTER SET latin1
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
            IGNORE 1 LINES
            (@col1, @col2, @col3, @col4) SET region = @col1, province = @col2, municipality = @col3, barangay = @col4
            ", addslashes($file_path));
     $data = DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
    }
```

Here is the Dump & Die (dd):

[image]

**And this is the result during Import**

[image]

**No error displayed, and no data being imported to the table**
Need help, I think the error is on my $file_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally I got it.**

correct command is

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

and not

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```